# How insert data array of object to db

Tags: javascript, arrays, query-builder, adonis.js

I want to insert the data like below:

```
"car" : [
       {
         "name": "toyota",
         "color": "red",
       },
       {
         "name": "hyundai",
         "color": "black",
       },
       {
         "name": "honda",
         "color": "grey",
       }
    ]
```

to database using adonis which is .ts, specifically in table cars with variable id, car_name, car_color. And I do this:

```
var i
for(i = 0; i<car.length; i++){
    await Database .table('cars')
                   .insert({
                      car_name: car[i].name,
                      car_color: car[i].color
                    })
}
```

Comment: First you need to re mapping array data before insert.
for example :

    const newCar = car.map(objCar => ({ car_name: objCar.name, car_color: objCar.color }))

then you can use multiInsert in adonis like bellow.

    await Database.table('cars').multiInsert(newCar)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to re mapping array data before insert.
for example :

```
const newCar = car.map(objCar => ({ car_name: objCar.name, car_color: objCar.color }))
```

then you can use multiInsert in adonis like bellow.

```
await Database.table('cars').multiInsert(newCar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`data property`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) in the initialization object.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const car = [
  {
    "name": "toyota",
    "color": "red",
  },
  {
    "name": "hyundai",
    "color": "black",
  },
  {
    "name": "honda",
    "color": "grey",
  }
];

$('#example').DataTable({
  "data": car,
  "columns": [
    { "data": "name" },
    { "data": "color" }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Color</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```